# Spring RabbitMQ SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory usage

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-rabbit

From the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#listener-concurrency), I want to use consume from queues by dynamically changing the consumers without restarting the application.

I do see that Spring RabbitMQ latest version supports the same, but no clue/example/explanation to change the same. I couldn't see proper source code for the same or how to pass params like `maxConcurrentConsumers`

I am using XML based configuration of Spring RabbitMQ along with Spring integration

```
<bean id="rabbitListenerContainerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="rabbitConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="3"/>
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
    <property name="acknowledgeMode" value="AUTO" />
</bean>

<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="lowInboundChannel" queue-names="lowLoadQueue" advice-chain="retryInterceptor" acknowledge-mode="AUTO" listener-container="rabbitListenerContainerFactory" />
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="highInboundChannel" queue-names="highLoadQueue" advice-chain="retryInterceptor" acknowledge-mode="AUTO" listener-container="rabbitListenerContainerFactory" />
```

Can anyone guide me how to dynamically configure the consumers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't share the same `rabbitListenerContainerFactory` for different `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>`s, because they do this:

```
protected void onInit() {
    this.messageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(new ChannelAwareMessageListener() {
```

So, only last adapter wins.
From other side there is even no reason to have several adapters. You can specify `queue-names="highLoadQueue,lowLoadQueue"` for a single adapter.
Although in case of `listener-container` you must specify `queues` on the `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory`.

If you want to change some `rabbitListenerContainerFactory` options at runtime, you can just inject it to some service and invoke its `setters`.

Let me know if I have missed anything.

Comment: sorry for late reply. so you are saying single adapter for different `queues`. Each queue will have it's own (different) payload. Why should we combine into single adapter?

so do we need to have multiple listenerContainerFactory for each `queue`? Why it's named as `Factory`, I thought it's single connection point to listen to multiple queues!!

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I really have missed that part. No, you can't use `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` for the `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>`. Its goal for the Annotation `@RabbitListener` configuration. For the XML config you should use `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` bean definition. And yes: separate bean for each  `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>`. Or just rely on the default container from the `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>`

Comment: I couldn't figure out the way still how to change dynamically the consumers. Can you please give me sample example/code/xml config?